# Wordpress SSO SAML

Tags: plugins, forum, single-sign-on, account

I made a wordpress for internal professional buisness. I'm looking to use SSO to accept users from my company in my wordpress forums.
I'm just looking a way to use SSO sAML in order to create accounts.

Is something like this is possible ? Is there any addons ? Any feedbacks ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you already have a working SAML IdP.  If so then it is a matter of configuring the SP (Service Provider).  Once those two criteria are set it is just a matter of figuring out the best plugin that meets your requirements:

1) custom plugin: Does exactly what you need but you need to develop it.

2) public plugins: There are a variety of them out there.  Make sure to find one that does what you need.  In your case provisioning. I am not going to recommend any specific one.  But you will find a list of them here - https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/saml

Comment: We use Shibboleth at my Enterprise.  I wrote multiple custom (Shibboleth) plugins.  I also wrote one simplesamlphp plugin, handed the code over to Pantheon, and one of their developers re-coded it to their standards.